# Get i18next to fallback to 'NO TRANSLATION'

Tags: javascript, translation, i18next

The i18next translation library by default seems to fallback to the translation key if no translation was found for the key, e.g.

```
// No translation defined for CANCEL yet
i18next.t('CANCEL') // Returns 'CANCEL'
```

If no translation is found for the key, I would prefer to fallback to a distinctive message that makes it obvious that we've missed a translation or mistyped a translation key. Preferably mentioning the key in the message e.g.

```
i18next.t('CANCEL') // Returns 'No translation found for "CANCEL"'
```

Some sort of fallback callback function would be ideal because then we could also log to console/remote service any missing translations.

How can I achieve something like this using the i18next library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it turns out i18next accepts a handler in the options when initialising that lets you set the value for missing keys.

```
i18n.init({
    ...

    saveMissing: true, // Must be set to true
    parseMissingKeyHandler: (key: string) => {
        return `No translation found for "${key}"`;
    }
})
```

Comment: But how to translate this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official documentation](https://www.i18next.com/configuration-options.html#missing-keys) `saveMissing` is **not** required for `parseMissingKeyHandler` to work. My code works fine without it.